# Add custom callback for a resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm using angularjs 1.1.5 and have a service provider for a resource, there is one use case where the returned response needs to be reparsed and some info need to be normalized, this is a special case but the resource is used across the project and it's not desired to have to use a different resource or custom filter everywhere it's called.

Is there a way I could add an extra function when returning from a query or a get method, but without affecting the normal behavior.

It should be something like, whenever there is a call to the resource get method, execute a callback do some transformations on the data and then return this data as expected.

Here is the way the service is currently implemented.

```
  factory('Seccion', ['$resource', 'api_url', function($resource, api_url) {
    var Seccion = $resource(api_url + 'secciones/:seccionId/:nestedResource/:nestedId',
      {
        seccionId: '@seccionId',
        nestedResource: '@nestedResource',
        nestedId: '@nestedId'
      },
      {
      getWithNotas: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          nestedResource: 'notas',
          order: 'fecha,desc;hora,desc',
          q: 'activo,=,1;borrado,=,0',
          count: 9,
          offset: 0
        }
      }
    });
    return Seccion;
  }])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke get method with callbacks. Here I am quoting from Angular [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) documentation.

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],    [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,    [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success],    [error])

So you can invoke your get method with callback like this :-

```
var s = Seccion.getWithNotas({params}, function() {
    doSomethingTo(s); 
}
```

Comment: Yes this is right, and it's what I'm using, but the problem is that I want this callback to be executed every time AND still be able to use another callback inside my controllers, for example when the ID for a _seccion_ is 32 there are some transformations that need to be done, this should be done automatically (not having to write the same callback function every time I want to use _Seccion_) and still be able to use the normal callbacks (having the transformed data already) inside my controllers and directives.

Comment: I think you should use [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). It will allow you to do many amazing things which ngResource won't allow.